# 8 Minute running with 5 minute rests okay?

Tags: running

Right now on average I am running about 8~9 minutes and then taking 5 minute rests. Is this a good pace or do I need to up the game more?

I repeat this about 6~7 times in about 1 hour.

Comment: What are your 'goals' here?  If it is too simply stay active then this is fine.  If you are working towards a performance goal you'll want to minimize the recovery at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're feeling fine at the end of the session, then there's no reason not to continue doing that. Also no huge reason to change the pace, but in general it's a good idea to either increase the distance you run in a particular time, or decrease the time it takes you to run a certain distance. For sustainability, aiming for something like cutting 5 seconds off each day would be fine, or alternately maybe add 20 meters at the same timing.

If you want to really inform yourself, getting a heart rate monitor would help, that way you can rest until your heart rate gets close to your resting heart rate, and run again instead of setting the rather arbitrary 5 minutes.

Comment: It would also be advisable to follow a 'vetted' program like C25K, because they have pretty much nailed the ratio between walking and jogging for absolute beginners. Otherwise, I completely agree, especially on the heart rate monitor.